# Show that a retract of a contractible space is contractible. - Is this proof legit?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

I am wondering if my proof is correct? Thank you very much.

> Show that a retract of a contractible space is contractible.

Given $X$ contracts to $x \in X$, we know there is a family of maps $f_t: X \to X, t \in I$, such that $f_0 = \mathbb{I}$ (the identity map), $f_1(X) = x$<strike>, and f_t|x=  \mathbb{I} for all t</strike>.

Consider a retract on $X$ to $A$, we know there is a map $r: X \to A$, such that $r(X) = A$, $r|_A = \mathbb{I}|_A$.

And now we set out to show that $A$ contracts to any $a \in A$, that is, there exists $\hat{f}$ such that $\hat{f}_t: A \to A, t \in I$, such that $\hat{f}_0 = \mathbb{I}$, $\hat{f}_1(A) = a$ <strike>, and f_t|a=  \mathbb{I} for all t</strike> .

But since $X$ retracts to $A$, that means $r$ brings any point $x \in X$ to some $a^\prime \in A$ homotopically. Therefore, we have a map from $X$ to $a^\prime$, which is the $\hat{f}$ we want when restricts to $A$. That is,
$$\hat{f}_t = r \circ f_t,$$
because it satisfies all the criterion we want:
$\hat{f}_0|_A = r \circ f_0|_A = r \circ \mathbb{I}|_A = \mathbb{I}|_A$, $\hat{f}_1(A) = r \circ f_1(A) = r \circ x = a^\prime$ <strike>which satisfy the condition that \hat{f}_1(A) = a for any a \in A, and f_t|a^\prime=  \mathbb{I} for all t</strike>.

Comment: You got the wrong definitions: $A$ being a retract of $X$ means only that there is a map $r:X\to A$ restricting to the identity on $A$. Also, you assumed a strong deformation retract to $x$, but contractible means that the identity on $X$ is null-homotopic, that is homotopic to the constant map $X\to x$, the homotopy need not fix $x$ during the time interval.

Comment: Dear @StefanH. - that is very helpful, thank you. I fixed it, does it look ok now? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should add more details and explain what you did to explicitly verify that $\hat f_t=r\circ f_t$ is the homotopy we want (which it is indeed).

Comment: I see, thank you very much @StefanH. I added at the last, and I hope it is better now.

Comment: You have to show that $\hat f_0(a)=a$ for each $a\in A$ and not such $\hat f_0(A)=A.$

Comment: Note that $r(a)=a$ for each $a\in A$. That $r$ restricts to the identity on $A$ does not just mean $r(A)=A.$

Comment: And you don't need to show that $\hat f_t(a')=a'$ for all $t$. That is only necessary for deformation retraction, not contractibility.

Comment: Thank you very much @StefanH. I meant $\hat{f}_0(a) = a$ by saying $\hat{f}_0(A) = \mathbb{I}(A)$, where $\mathbb{I}(A)$ means the identity map on $A$.

Comment: But $f(A)=A$ is not the same as $f(a)=a$, it just means that for each $b\in A$ there is an $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)\in A$.

Comment: Oh, by $\mathbb{I}$ I explicitly mean identity map @StefanH.

Comment: Maybe you want to say $\hat f_0|_A=\Bbb I|_A$. Remember, $f(A)$ is a set, $f|_A$ is the function restricted to $A$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I think your way is clear. thank you~

Comment: Sorry for being stubburn - but is there real difference between $\hat{f}_0|_A = \mathbb{I}_A$ and $\hat{f}_0(A) = \mathbb{I}(A)$? Thank you @StefanH.

Comment: Of course. If $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $A=\{a,b\}$ and $f(a)=b, f(b)=a, f(c)=c$. What is $f(A)$? And what is $f|_A$?

Comment: Oh I see. That is a big mistake. Because I just realized $\mathbb{I}(A)$ is the image set of $A$! I meant to say the function.. Thank you @StefanH.!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure you'll keep in mind that the one thing is a function, the other thing is a set :-)

Comment: Yes yes I will keep that in mind @StefanH. :-)

Comment: Ok, and finally get rid of all the wrong $\hat{f}_t(a^\prime) = a^\prime$s. Thanks again, @StefanH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are still some inconsistencies in your text:

> Consider a retract on $X$ to $A$, we know there is a map $r:X→A,$ such that 
>   $r(X)=A,$ $r(A)=A.$

This still has to be corrected. It should better say: "$r:X\to A$ such that $r|_A=\Bbb I|_A$"

> $\hat f_1(A)=a$ for any $a∈A$

That can be deleted. You already know that $\hat f_1(A)=\{a'\}$ and that is all you want.

Comment: I see, thank you very much Stefan!

Comment: Also the formula "$r(X)=A$" is not wrong but unnecessary, because $r|_A=\Bbb I|_A$ tells you that each $a$ in $A$ is image of itself under $r$, so the range of $r$ contains $A$ and, conversely, is contained in $A$ since $r:X\to A$.